# Does the category of polynomials sending one ideal to another capture anything about a ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, category-theory, ideals

I'm learning a little bit about rings and modules. I'm interested in objects that can be used to inspect or talk about multiple ideals at once that aren't related by inclusion.

One idea I had is a collection of polynomials with coefficients taken from $R$ that sends $I$ to a subset of $J$, where $I$ and $J$ are ideals of a fixed ring $R$.

**We can organize these polynomials into homsets and make a category where the objects are the ideals. Does this category capture anything interesting about the underlying ring?**

For example, if our ring is $\mathbb{Z}$ and $I = 2\mathbb{Z}$ and $J = 3 \mathbb{Z}$, then the polynomial $x^3-x = (x-1)(x)(x+1)$ sends $I$ to $J$. Granted, $x^3 - x$ also sends $\mathbb{Z}$ to $J$, so it can be extended, I'm not sure whether this fact tells us something.

The polynomials within a given homset are closed under $+$, $*$ and scalar multiplication.

$p(I) \subset J$ and $q(I) \subset J$ implies $(pq)(I) \subset p(I)q(I) \subset J$.

$p(I) \subset J$ and $q(I) \subset J$ implies $(p+q)(I) \subset p(I) + q(I) \subset J$.

$p(I) \subset J$ implies $rp(I) \subset rJ \subset J$.

We have an identity function $x$ in each homset. It is a compositional identity but not an additive or multiplicative one.

As a category, we do not have an initial object but we do have an almost-terminal object. From any nonzero ideal $I$, the only arrow going to $0$ is the $0$ polynomial. However, the any polynomial with a zero constant term is in $\text{Hom}(0, 0)$.

Another interesting fact in the case of the integers is that a polynomial is in $\text{Hom}(I, I)$ if and only if its constant term is in $I$.

Also, a polynomial $p(x)$ is in $\text{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}, J)$ if and only if its forward difference $p(x+1)-p(x)$ is constantly zero mod $J$ and $p(0)$ is in $J$.

Anyway, I'm wondering whether this category is really trivial in some sense or actually tells us something about the ring that was used to build it.

Comment: here is an equivalent category. The objects are closed subschemes of $Spec(R)$. A morphism $Z\to W$ between two closed subschemes is a morphism $p:\mathbb A_R \to \mathbb A_R$ of schemes such that whenever $f:Spec(R)\to \mathbb A_R$ is a function which vanishes on $Z$ (that is $f|_Z=0$), then $pf$ is a morphism which vanishes on $W$. This is very strange, and I have never seen it before!

Comment: @Nico, I don't know algebraic geometry, so I don't really understand your alternative construction. Is this category trivial or boring from an algebraic geometric perspective, or just odd?

Comment: I am sorry, but I have no idea how (non)trivial your category is.